# Blog .htaccess - fancy formatting for $_GET values

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

**Desired result:**

```
Browser displays:
http://example.com/blog/2015/8/10/1/  

While the source page loaded is:
http://example.com/blog/post?y=2015&m=8&d=10&id=1
```

**Current code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    #START FANCY BLOG URL BUILDER

    RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/  http://example.com/blog/post.php?y=$1=&m=$2&d=$3&id=$4 [QSA]

    #END FANCY BLOG URL BUILDER

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

> **Note:** not all the code shown is used to produce the desired results.

**Unintended result:**

```
Browser displays:
http://example.com/blog/post?y=2015&m=8&d=10&id=1

While the source page loaded is:
http://example.com/blog/2015/8/10/1/
```

**The struggle:**

I did my best to find to find out how to alter the url. I'm unaware if the proceeding code may be conflicting the rewrite rule. It may also be useful to note that I have hosting with godaddy.com Any suggestions and/or comments would be very appreciated.

I've been  fighting this problem for around ***2 or 3 hours*** now.

Thanks.

Comment: If your rewriting target starts with ` http://…` you'll get an implicit `[R]` redirect.

Comment: note that if your browser is showing the un-pretty urls, you're either not rewriting properly, or you're sending out the urly urls in your html to begin with. any urls you send to the browser MUST be the "clean" ones.

Comment: @mario If you'd to add that as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. Editing the line to: RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?  blog/post.php?y=$1=&m=$2&d=$3&id=$4 [QSA] fixed the problem.